# .NET:ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE in Hangout Integration

Tags: google-api

I am using Google Api for Hangout Button-

https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js

Instead of linking the file using https link i can download the file and link it locally. By doing this, will it cause any issues??

Reason for me doing this - Because Sometimes the chrome throws error - .NET:ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE in loading the file. Linking this file locally would solve this.

Comment: Have you looked up for https problem because sometimes it may cause a problem???

Comment: The https problem occurs when we try to access http content inside https content. But my website is on http and trying to access https content inside it shouldn't create any problems.

Comment: What kind of issues are you afraid of? if you are doing it already sometimes that is the best way to verify whether there are issues or not :)

Comment: Caching platform.js on your server is not recommended. The contents of it changes and not having the latest version could cause your integrations to break. A better approach is to identify why the insecure response is getting triggered and see if it's possible to stop that.

Comment: @abraham I know caching js file on my server might cause some issues in future. But I am not able to find out why this file triggers Insecure Response.